# Copy and Paste Column to another column

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I want to search through column headings to find a heading that contains the text "CountryCode".
I want to **cut** this column and paste it into the sixth column.

I know `Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5")`is wrong.

Screen Shot: Country Code was in Column W. I want to paste into the new F column.
[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W1:W3").Cut _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5")
            Columns([23]).EntireColumn.Delete
            Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    '~~> If not found
    Else
            MsgBox "Country Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your "problematic" code is already inside the `With ws` (`ws` already defined and set to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`). so inside the loop you need to modify `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W1:W3")` to `.Range("W1:W3")` , and also `Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5")` to `Destination:=.Range("E5")` , in case these are the target and destination of your Copy > Paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code do what you are looking for?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    '~~> Cut the entire column
    aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

    '~~> Insert the column here
    Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Else
    MsgBox "Country Not Found"

    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You the man :-) Thank you so much this worked like a charm. Thank you for the assistance much respect from Dublin :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Delete or Insert.  `Range().Cut Destination:=Range()` will move the cells into position for you.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=.Columns(5)
        Else
            MsgBox "Country Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your clean solution better :)