# Copy a workbook's column to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to copy a column from one workbook to another depending on the column header. However I am getting a `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` error each time.

I am following two other questions from SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894035/vba-copy-and-paste-column-based-of-column-heading) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754791/excel-macro-to-copy-certain-columns-from-one-workbook-to-another). However the line of code that it fails on seems to work for the other OP in question [2].

```
Sub Autofill()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, target_column As Range

    'read csv and convert to excel

    tx_design_file_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover").Range("E10").Value

    Set tx_design_file_workbook = Workbooks.Open(tx_design_file_name)

    tx_design_file_workbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    tx_design_file_workbook.Close savechanges:=False


    Set compt_template = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template\CoMPT_Convert_Template.xlsx")


    Set target_column = compt_template.Worksheets(1).Columns("A")


    Set data_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")

    Dim aCell As Range


    With data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:="SiteName", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=target_column
        Else
            MsgBox "SiteName not found"
        End If
    End With

    output_path_name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output\CoMPT_Convert.xlsx"
    compt_template.SaveAs (output_path_name)
    'target_column.SaveAs (output_path_name)

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the line to this and try again: `Set target_column = compt_template.Worksheets(1).Columns("A4")`

Comment: Also: `Range("E" & 10)` is the same as `Range("E10")`, makes it a bit easier to read. :)

Comment: Also you're dimensioning `targetColumn As Range` but calling it later as `Set target_column`

Comment: @M.Schalk have amended, but when I save it, nothing has changed, I am saving `compt_template` should I be saving `target_column` instead?

Comment: @jamheadart have amended code

Comment: @jamheadart is right, you need to change `targetColumn As Range` to `target_column As Range`

Comment: @mp252 No, saving `compt_template` is correct

Comment: Does thisworkbook actually have a sheet called Cover?

Comment: perfect works now, only issue is am I able to paste from cell A4 onwards, as it threw an error when I tried; `Set target_column = compt_template.Worksheets(1).Columns("A4")`

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I think that you did a typo :

```
Sub Autofill()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, target_column As Range

    'read csv and convert to excel

    tx_design_file_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("E10").Value

    Set tx_design_file_workbook = Workbooks.Open(tx_design_file_name)

    tx_design_file_workbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    tx_design_file_workbook.Close savechanges:=False


    Set compt_template = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template\CoMPT_Convert_Template.xlsx")


    Set target_column = Workbooks("CoMPT_Convert_Template").Worksheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).row)


    Set data_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")

    Dim aCell As Range


    With data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:="SiteName", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=target_column
        Else
            MsgBox "SiteName not found"
        End If
    End With

    output_path_name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output\CoMPT_Convert.xlsx"
    compt_template.SaveAs (output_path_name)
    'target_column.SaveAs (output_path_name)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I need to past the values to cell A4 onwards, but this did line of code did not allow me; `Set target_column = compt_template.Worksheets(1).Columns("A4")`

Comment: @mp252 Did you try `Set target_column = Workbooks("CoMPT_Convert_Template").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")`

Comment: yes, but I need to put it in the A4 cell to start from the A4 cell

Comment: @mp252 then do `Set target_column = Workbooks("CoMPT_Convert_Template").Worksheets(1).Range("A4")` Please tell me if it does the job

Comment: Unfortunately not, I got a runtime error 1004, "Copy and paste aread cannot overlap unless they are the same size and shape."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200072/discussion-between-mp252-and-dorian).

Comment: @mp252 Can not access chat here So please talk here then we will delete comment once we solved ur issue

Comment: still not unfortunately, maybe I need to try another way. My aim is to copy data from one excel file to another, but I don't want to consider the first row of the data I am copying, and I want to paste it into the 4th row of the of the other workbook, so copy entire column from 2nd onwards where keyword in header, and then paste to 4th row onwards. If that makes sense